# php preg_split split string to array from square brackets

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I want to split the string from square brackets without removing any character. I tried the below code but it's not working for me.

```
$value = "<p>&nbsp;Lorem ipsum dolor [State] sit amet, consectetur [City] adipisicing [TopJob7] elit, sed do eiusmod [JobType]</p>";

$tagsReplace = preg_split('/[\[]*[\][]/U', $value, -1);

echo '<pre>';
print_r( $tagsReplace );
exit;
```

When I run the above code I got the output like

```
Array
(
    [0] => <p>&nbsp;Lorem ipsum dolor 
    [1] => State
    [2] =>  sit amet, consectetur 
    [3] => City
    [4] =>  adipisicing 
    [5] => TopJob7
    [6] =>  elit, sed do eiusmod 
    [7] => JobType
    [8] => </p>
)
```

I want output like below.

```
Array
(
    [0] => <p>&nbsp;Lorem ipsum dolor 
    [1] => [State]
    [2] =>  sit amet, consectetur 
    [3] => [City]
    [4] =>  adipisicing 
    [5] => [TopJob7]
    [6] =>  elit, sed do eiusmod 
    [7] => [JobType]
    [8] => </p>
)
```

Please help me where I did a mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pattern `[\[]*[\][]` matches 0+ times an opening bracket and then either a opening or closing bracket giving you either a `[` or n `]`

To keep the delimiters you could capture in a group matching from `[` to `]` and match what is in between using a negated character class  matching not a closing bracket.

Use the `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` flag to keep the delimiter.

Note that you don't need the `/U` flag.

```
(\[[^]]+\])
```

**Explanation**

- `(` Capturing group

  - `\[` Match `[`
  - `[^]]+` Match 1+ times not a `]`
  - `\]` Match `]`
- `)` Close group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AmSFss/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/L1smn)

For example:

```
$value = "<p>&nbsp;Lorem ipsum dolor [State] sit amet, consectetur [City] adipisicing [TopJob7] elit, sed do eiusmod [JobType]</p>";
$tagsReplace = preg_split('/(\[[^]]+\])/', $value, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
print_r( $tagsReplace );
```